# How to find all occurrence of a substring?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to find all the occurrences of `aa` in the string `aaabaa` using `re` module of Python.

My code:

```
import re
s=input()
s1=input()
m=re.compile('(?<='+s1[0]+')'+s1[1:len(s1)])
for i in m.finditer(s):
    print(i.span())
```

Actual output:

```
(1, 2)(2, 3)(5, 6)
```

Desired output:

```
(0, 1)(1, 2)(4, 5)
```

I can't find where this is going wrong.

How can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
for i in re.finditer(r'(?=(aa)).', s):
    print(i.span())
```

Comment: actually my question was for any valid sub-string and string like -aba- in -aabcabcabab-

Comment: @rajivdas: in this case you need to build it yourself using the starting position and the substring length (or the capture group length if you use a pattern in place of the substring).